# AWS Lambda NodeJS locale/variable isolation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

There is a concern about potential problem with reusable variables in `aws-lambda`.

A user's locale is passed as
`Browser cookies` => `AWS API Gateway` => `Lambda (NodeJS 6.10)`

On the server side localization is implemented with a static variable in a class. Presenting `typescript` code for clarity but can be done in pure ECMAScript.

#### Module Language.ts

```
export default class Language
{
    public static Current: LanguageCode = LanguageCode.es;
}
```

Static `Language.Current` variable is used across different parts of the application for manual localization and it works perfectly on the client side (`react` + `redux`).

#### Lambda function

```
import {APIGatewayEvent, Context, Callback} from 'aws-lambda';
import Language from './pathToModule/Language.ts';

export const api = function(event: APIGatewayEvent, context: Context, callback: Callback)
{
    Language.Current = event.headers.cookie.locale;

    // do the logic here
}
```

#### Potential problem

According to AWS documentation NodeJS instances can be reused for different requests. It means that famous concurrent problems have to be considered, e.g.

- *User 1* calls lambda function. The locale is set to *English*.
- In parallel *user 2* calls the same lambda instance. The local is changed to *Spanish*.
- *User 1* code continues and reads modified (wrong) locale variable from the shared module `Language`.

How do you resolve this problem?

For convenience it is good to have only one place for locale change. As I understand the same concern exists for all famous i18n npm packages (i18next, i18n, yahoo i18n, etc).

Comment: An instance will only ever serve a single request at a time. If two users connected at the same time then two instances would be spun up. The instances do get re-used, but only after the initial request has been responded to.

Comment: thank you @idbehold, is there any official documentation to prove the statement for `nodejs`? (cannot find it myself)

Comment: I can try to find documentation on this, but you can pretty easily test it yourself. Set some `var count = 0` outside your handler, have the handler `setTimeout(() => ctx.success(++count), 2000)` and then try invoking it multiple time at once, then try sequential invocations.

Comment: @idbehold Nice! The documentation will be good, so everybody will know that it is not a temporal/custom behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best practices for Lambda functions is to try and not write code which maintains state.

Here you are initializing the locale based on an initial request and applying it to all future requests, which is inherently flawed even on server based code, forget server less.

To fix this, you will need to initialize the localization library for each request, or at least maintain an in memory lazy map, which you can make use of use the current request's locale to achieve the desired localization.

Comment: totally understand the problem, any particular good example? I don't want to pass `{locale}` variable back and force across all the constructors or methods on my domain models/messages, that's unacceptable. For example, .NET team achieves this by placing locale in current `Thread.Context`, which is independent from different calls, don't know about NodeJS model.

Comment: I doubt if you would be able to achieve this without refactoring the code. It is always good to keep the current invocation context in the scope of a method or at a class level and not rely on static initializations.

Comment: Also, javascript doesnt have a thread context as such or an  equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions:

1. Node JS container is reused only after a [function process is finished](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-introduction.html) (`callback` or `error` is occurred) (thanks to @idbehold). Thus there is always a unique context per a function call.
2. Refactor code and pass a locale variable back and force (@Yeshodhan Kulkarni suggestion).
   For example, return a function as an intermediate result and use it before calling the result back.
   `var localizableResult = ...;`
   `var result = localizableResult.Localize(requestedLocale)`.
3. If there is a need to use a local stack (kind of a thread context) for other projects there is a npm package [node-continuation-local-storage](https://github.com/othiym23/node-continuation-local-storage).

`Case 1` makes it really simple to use global variables for current locale.